# Cannot display items from list in ViewData Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am new to ASP.NET and MVC 2. I'm trying to iterate over a list of lists of strings within my view page. However I cannot get any data to be displayed.

Controller Code.

```
 public class RCADSChildController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /RCADSChild/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new RCADSChildViewModel();
        ViewData["DataList"] = model.Data;
        ViewData["Count"] = model.Amount;

        Debug.WriteLine(model.Amount);


        return View(model);
    }

}
```

Model

```
public class RCADSChildViewModel
{
    public int Amount { get; set;}
    public List<List<String>> Data { get; set; }

    public RCADSChildViewModel()
    {
        Queries connect = new Queries();
        Data = connect.getQuestionData();
        Amount = Data.Count;
    }
}
```

View

```
<div class="col-md-6">
             <% 

                foreach (List<String> list in ViewData["DataList"] as List<List<String>>)
                     {
                        list[0].ToString();
                        list[1].ToString();
                        list[2].ToString();
                        list[3].ToString();     
                     }
             %>
```

The lists are definitely populated with data as I have checked using Debug.WriteLine().

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why in the world are you using `ViewData` when you already passing the values in your model?

Answer (score 0):

You are simply converting them to string and not actually writing them out.

I believe you will want something like:

```
         <% 

            foreach (List<String> list in ViewData["DataList"] as List<List<String>>)
                 { %>
                    <%= list[0].ToString(); %>
                    <%= list[1].ToString(); %>
                    <%= list[2].ToString(); %>
                    <%= list[3].ToString(); %>
               <%  
                 }
         %>
```